# How to escape Angularjs Lexer parsing on a Json parameter?

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm giving a 880 Ko Json (which is the serialization of a C# model) to my Angularjs Init function like this:

```
@{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, JsonUtils.getMyJsonSerializerSettings());
}
<div ng-controller="FactureController"
     ng-cloak=""
     ng-init="init(@json)">
```

The problem is Angularjs Lexer parse the entire expression in the directive ng-init including this big json and it takes several time (20 sec)!

Is there a way to escape the parsing of the json?

Comment: have you tried [`$sce.trustAs(type, value);`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: I just tried giving this to the init function `$sce.trustAs($sce.JS, @json)` but it returns undefined

Comment: And the same with `$sce.trustAsJs(@json)`